# Children's Book, Characters Made of Vegetables

Tags: identification-request

My sister and I had a book when we were children (late 1980s, early 1990s at a push). The artwork was quite grown up and quite creepy for a children's book. The characters were made up of a variety of realistic vegetables, and the color scheme was quite muted.

I remember one picture where a character was underground and was able to listen above ground through an earhorn device. I think a Father Time was also in it. The book is not "The Adventures of Cipollino" by Gianni Rodari.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange! Please look through the suggestions in the [tag wiki](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) for identification requests and [edit](https://literature.stackexchange.com/posts/25781/edit) your question to include additional information. For example, can you describe the artwork more specifically? What do "grown-up" and "creepy" mean here? Also, was the book intended for babies, children around 10 years old, or ... ? Such details will help narrow down possibilities. Thanks!

Comment: I may be looking for the same book. Did the anthropomorphic vegetables take a girl underground to punish humans for eating vegetables? The book I had was for children perhaps 9-11.

Comment: That sounds somewhat familiar but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @bobble - I don't see anything forbidding a tag like [picture-books] in the 'How do I tag questions properly' post. Can you explain why it's not useful? Is there a relevant meta-discussion? (The guidance for ID-requests says "add author, language, and/or **medium** tags if known." Though I'm not sure if picture books are a medium...)

Comment: @CDR medium tags are reserved for very short works like [poetry] or [essays], full books don't have them (e.g. no [novel]). See [the proposal for medium tags](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/487/11259)